# Can a project created with qmake be compiled without using qmake?

Tags: c++, qmake

I have some source code that was built with qmake. Compiling it is supposed to be done with `qmake qmakefile.pro`.

I'd like to compile it *without* using qmake. Is that even possible? What would the steps be?

Edit: [Here's the .pro file](http://pastebin.com/viv204Fv).

Comment: The program 'qmake' is a tool to help you generate Makefile or project files, then you can doing the building with make or IDE. What you said is possible, but you have to create your own Makefile or project file manually without qmake.

Comment: That's my problem-- it's already been built with qmake; I'd like to compile it without qmake, if possible. I'll edit the question.

Comment: cmake is a popular alternative to qmake.

Comment: @felwithe A couple of questions to help get a more useful answer:  Why are you adverse to using QMake?  What is the problem you are trying to solve for which not building with QMake appears to be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compile files without `qmake`.

You need to get any specific compiler settings from `qmake` and convert them to the other compiler as necessary.

Or you can convert the contents of the `qmake.pro` file into a *makefile* or your IDE's project settings.

If the `qmake.pro` is not a human readable text file, you will have to launch `qmake` and retrieve the settings.  Otherwise search for a conversion tool.

Comment: Research and study *makefiles*, then attempt reading the `qmake.pro` file.

Comment: Most questions on this site could be answered by learning a new language instead of asking.

Answer (score 0):

While it is technically possible to translate the .pro file into something else, I would not advise it.

Why?

- QMake does a lot of work behind the scenes.

  - In the case of the .pro file you referenced (http://pastebin.com/viv204Fv), QMake is invoking meta-tools (uic, moc) to create the code for the UI and adding build rules to compile it.  You will need to manually code those in your build script.
    -. QMake also solves issues of choosing the right compiler and linker options (including the right include files).  You will need to determine them yourself and add them to your build script.
- The project is already using Qt, so why not use Qt's build script generating tool, QMake?  If you have installed a Qt development environment, you should already have qmake installed.

Comment: I spent an hour installing the various packages for it. Then some more, than some more, some config stuff, more packages, and it still gave me errors. It's just a make program, it shouldn't have more dependencies than an operating system. I decided I'd rather try to do without it, or simply find a binary of what I need, on general principle of software like that pisses me off.